# Map file format for Real-time strategy game

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ios, rts, map-editor

I am planing to create a 2D RTS game on iPhone using cocos2d, besides the tile map, any other suggestion for storing the map details for the game?

Would be nice if a GUI editor is also provided.

Answer (score 3):

A good idea is to build a map editor into the game, invoked with a hotkey when the game is paused in debug builds.  It allows you to quickly edit the map during development gameplay and will save you masses of time.

And it might grow into an extra feature of the game if you polish it enough later for end users.

Answer (score 3):

While a dedicated map editor is great to have, it's also quite time consuming to make. The #1 easy shortcut is to define your map format as a subset of a bitmap image format and use a bitmap editor to make the maps. How well this works depend greatly on the requirements for the map, it's easy if the number of different options for each tile fit into a small palette, if not you may have to use multiple pixels for each tile, which complicate the matter and make the solution less optimal.